# Facebook's sharer API doesn't work for the new "Timeline" layout

Tags: facebook, facebook-sharer

Today I realized that my share buttons doesn't work for the new Facebook layout - **Timeline**. When I was using the **Wall** everything was working. But now I'm with the **Timeline** and can't share anything, so I think all the users which are using the **Timeline** and not the **Wall** can't share with my buttons at all. The popup appears but the fields are empty and when form is submitted it says something like "The post can't be shared (or saved) to this Wall" (I translated it because my Facebook is not in English). For my buttons I am using `sharer.php`:

```
https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?app_id=<app_id>&sdk=joey&u=<url>&display=popup
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sharer.php` endpoint has been officially deprecated for more than a year. It looks like Facebook might be in the process of disabling it now.

You should switch to either the [Send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) or the [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) method.

Comment: Thanks. I think, Feed Dialog can substitute the Sharer API.